# Tutorials on how to connect/manipulate sql server with vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Please I need Tutorials on how to connect/manipulate sql server with vb.net.

Comment: See following for common steps:
http://urenjoy.blogspot.com/2008/10/how-to-set-or-test-connection-string.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to [windowsclient.net](http://windowsclient.net) for winforms or [asp.net](http://asp.net) for webforms.  Each of these sites has a lot of information which you can use.  HTH